# stream_set_timeout never works no matter how low the timeout

Tags: php, sockets, fsockopen

In PHP, I'm opening a stream, writing to it and then reading from it. I want to set a timeout on the reading of the stream but no matter how low I set this (0 microseconds, 10 microseconds) the meta data never shows "timed_out"!

Relevant code:

```
//open the socket
if ( $fp = fsockopen( gethostbyname(host), port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout ) ) {

    //Send command to the host
    if ( fwrite( $fp, $requestCommand ) ) {
        //Set timeout and blocking
        stream_set_blocking( $fp, FALSE );
        stream_set_timeout( $fp, 0, 10 ); 

        //Check for timeout
        $info = stream_get_meta_data( $fp );
        echo $info[ 'timed_out' ];

        //Read and check for timeout
        while ( !$info['timed_out'] && !feof( $fp ) ) {
            $response .= fread( $fp, 4096 );

            //Get meta data (which has timeout info)
            $info = stream_get_meta_data( $fp );
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are executing this in CLI or browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key I found is the `stream_set_blocking($fp, TRUE )`.

If `FALSE`, then `$status['timed_out']` seems to not have any practical effect.  `TRUE` [PHP default] works.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! The examples I'd seen on PHP's website had it set to FALSE and for some reason it never occurred to me to try it as blocking. Do you know if this is the way the API "contract" should be working?